# Remove first row of csv file with fast-csv in node js

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm using the fast-csv node module to parse a csv and it's parsed successfully but i don't want the title of the fields. The output looks like this

```
[ 'ID', 'Date', 'Description', 'Amount' ]
ID
desc Description
[ '1', '12/4/30', 'kebab ab  ', '-1900.00' ]
```

the first row is the title of the fields but want to remove them from the output. How do i do it?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`headers` option](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv#parsing) to `true` to have it ignore the first line:

```
const parser = csv({ headers : true });
```

Comment: My problem is a little different, there is one line and then comes the header. I tried to set skipLines: 1 and headers: true, but can't make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: @GuilhermeSampaio should work, at least [a simple example](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/134c6ed85ed7435cbbf4614101400bdf) does.